# Update a file in public folder of play framework

Tags: playframework

I have a javascript file at public/javascripts/test.js of play framework. I want to replace the @serverURL with something like http://example.com/ when play framework is started. Is there a way for me to do that?

```
    var serverURL = @serverURL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can have such substitution in Play public assets.

Instead I would have something like following in the view (e.g. `file.html.scala`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">var serverURL="@serverURL"</script>
<script src="public/javascripts/test.js"></script>
```